# Как называется этот эффект? И как его реализовать на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать эффект при переключении этих вкладок на этом сайте http://sitesdepot.ru/works/focalfolio/ с помощью JS.

А именно, когда картинки плавно появляются при переключении.

Comment: Анимация в CSS 3 не подойдет?<br>Видео [урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftCxJzgE47U) по теме.

Comment: Я не нашел там никаких котиков.

Comment: @Дмытрык, заменил ссылку, случайно не ту добавил

Comment: Так и не понял о каком эффекте речь

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, когда переключаешь кнопочки "Themes", "Icons", картинки не резко появляются, а плавно.

Comment: Штука называется "изотоп"

Answer (score 3):

Эффект называется "CSS-трансформация".

К блокам с картинками применены сразу по два таких эффекта: `translate` (изменение расположения) и `scale` (изменение размера).

Дополнительно меняется прозрачность (`opacity`).

Ну а эффект плавной анимации достигается за счет задания времени перехода из одного состояния в другое (`transition-duration`).

Самое забавное, что на "чистом JS" не получится - даже если делать все скриптом, как минимум для изменения прозрачности придется все равно дергать стиля методом `%element%.style.opacity = "%value%"`.

Ну и главный вопрос: зачем? CSS-изменения браузер обработает гораздо быстрее и эфективнее.

Comment: не знал, что можно сделать только с помощью CSS